# Código Python no html não está funcionando corretamente

Tags: html, python-3.x, django

Estou usando `Python` e `Django` para uma aplicação web, em certo momento faço o seguinte código no `html`:

```
{% for oportunidade in all_oportunidades %}
    <a>{{oportunidade.categoria}}</a>
    <br>
    {% if oportunidade.categoria == 1 %}
        <a>teste</a>
        <br>
    {%endif%}
{% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

O resultado que estou obtendo é o seguinte:

```
None
2
0
1
1
2
None
```

Mas o resultado que eu espero é o seguinte:

```
None
2
0
1
teste
1
teste
2
None
```

O que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: Tente fazer assim if oportunidade.categoria == '1'

Comment: Ou tente desta forma  if int(oportunidade.categoria) == 1

Comment: Funcionou com aspas simples, obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Soluções

**Comparando strings**

Sua variável `categoria` não é um inteiro, então você precisa fazer a comparação usando aspas, passando a representação para `string`, como neste exemplo.

```
{% for oportunidade in all_oportunidades %}
    <a>{{oportunidade.categoria}}</a>
    <br>
    {% if oportunidade.categoria == "1" %}
        <a>teste</a>
        <br>
    {%endif%}
{% endfor %}
```

**Comparando inteiros**

Ou então, você pode converter a sua variável para inteiro da seguinte forma.

```
{% for oportunidade in all_oportunidades %}
    <a>{{oportunidade.categoria}}</a>
    <br>
    {% if int(oportunidade.categoria) == 1 %}
        <a>teste</a>
        <br>
    {%endif%}
{% endfor %}
```

## Melhor método

**Minha opnião**

Acredito que a melhor solução para o seu problema seja converter a valor para inteiro, já que há a possibilidade de uma comparação com um valor inteiro, ou seja, vamos supor que em um determinado momento o valor de "categoria" seja 1 porem do tipo inteiro, ele não vai mostrar o `<a>teste</a><br>`.

## Teste

**Teste 1**

```
valor = 1

if valor == '1':
  print("primeiro")

if valor == 1:
  print("segundo")
```

*Resultado*

> segundo

[Executar](https://repl.it/talk/share/Teste-1/10681?id=10681)

**Teste 2**

```
valor = "1"

if valor == "1":
  print("primeiro")

if valor == 1:
  print("segundo")
```

*Resultado*

> primeiro

[Executar](https://repl.it/talk/share/Teste-2/10678?id=10678)

**Teste 3**

```
valor = "1"

if int(valor) == 1:
  print("primeiro")

if str(valor) == "1":
  print("segundo")
```

*Resultado*

> primeiro
>   segundo

[Executar](https://repl.it/talk/share/Teste-3/10679?id=10679)

**Teste 4**

```
valor = 1

if int(valor) == 1:
  print("primeiro")

if str(valor) == "1":
  print("segundo")
```

*Resultado*

> primeiro
>   segundo

[Executar](https://repl.it/talk/share/Teste-4/10680?id=10680)

## Conclusão

É sempre bom saber o tipo da variável antes de fazer uma comparação, em especial em linguagem que não é "tipada" como é o caso do python, porém se o seu problema não permite ter uma previsão de qual será o tipo, é bom fazer a conversão, assim mesmo que receba um tipo não esperado na conversão isso será solucionado, como nos teste 3 e 4.